# Swift Charts Format Not Working

Tags: swift

I am using the Charts framwork for Swift found [here](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts). I have a chart that I am trying to fix two issues shown in the chart below:

[image]

The first is trying to format my X values from doubles to Ints. I want the value to show 67 and not 67.0. I have tried the following to adjust it but 
numbers still stay the same:

```
let format = NumberFormatter()
format.minimumIntegerDigits = 0
format.minimumFractionDigits = 0

let formatter = DefaultValueFormatter(formatter: format)

chartview.rightAxis.valueFormatter = (formatter as? IAxisValueFormatter)
```

I also have a problem where the buttom bars dont line up with the buttom of the graph. If you look at the graph above, it looks like 0 starts above the X axis and not at the orgin. Theres a little space below the bars. I would like the bottom of each bar to touch the X-Axis.

Comment: Can you check that you are setting formatter to rightAxis? I think you have to set formatter to the DataSet.

Comment: the last line of my code is: chartview.rightAxis.valueFormatter = (formatter as? IAxisValueFormatter). Shouldn't that set it to the rightAxis?

Comment: Did you tried setting formatter to dataset?

Comment: How do you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try like this :

```
let format = NumberFormatter()
format.minimumIntegerDigits = 0
format.minimumFractionDigits = 0

let formatter = DefaultValueFormatter(formatter: format)

let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "Label") // replace with your set
chartDataSet.valueFormatter = formatter
```

For lining Button bars. please try this:

```
barChartView.rightAxis.axisMinimum = 0.0
barChartView.leftAxis.axisMinimum = 0.0
```

Comment: Edited the answer. Please check.