# iOS Charts Double to Int Swift

Tags: swift, ios-charts

I am using the Charts library found [here](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts).

I have a chart that is showing each bar label as a double like 15.0 instead of 15. I hear you have to use valueFormatter to change the values but not sure how to implement it. So far I have:

```
let format = NumberFormatter()

    format.numberStyle = .none

    let formatter = DefaultValueFormatter(formatter: format)

   BarChartData.setValueFormatter(formatter) // error here
```

I am getting:

> instance member setValueFormatter can not be used on type ChartData

Comment: `BarChartData` seems to be a class and not a instance.

Comment: Try [searching on the error](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+instance+member+can+not+be+used+on+type)

Comment: Do you know how to change data format of the chart labels?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check you can use like this :

```
let chartData = BarChartData(dataSet: chartDataSet)

let format = NumberFormatter()
format.numberStyle = .none
let formatter = DefaultValueFormatter(formatter: format)

chartData.setValueFormatter(formatter)
```

Comment: Would you happen to know how to solve the issue here: 
https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/issues/2751

Comment: Did you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45901182/swift-charts-format-not-working